# Trying to select the closest Image to a button but Jquery is returning Undefined

Tags: jquery, dom

Here are the buttons with the data I am trying to select. Basically I would Like to get the source attribute of the Image that corresponds to the button that is clicked.

```
<div class="row">
               <!-- Available car 1 start -->
              <div class="col-md-12 available_car">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 available_car_img">
                  <img src="http://www.sweetheartmotors.ca/sites/default/files/audi_PNG1736.png" style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
                  <p>Car Name 1</p>
                  <p> 5 Seater </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 available_car_info col-xs-8">
                  <div class="features col-md-12 pull-left ">
                      <p class="features-header">Car Features</p>
                      <P><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>Air conditioning</p>
                      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color"></span>Automatic</p>
                      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>3 Bags</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="available_car_prices col-xs-12 col-md-7" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                  <div class="price-box price-box-left col-sm-3">
                    <h4 class="price-heading">Rental price</h4>
                    <h4 class="price-amount">$143.00</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-box price-box-middle col-sm-5">
                    <h4 class="price-heading">Total Price</h4>
                    <h4 class="price-amount">$143.00</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-box price-box-right col-sm-3">
                    <h4 class="price-heading">Free Milage</h4>
                    <h4 class="price-amount">$143.00</h4>
                  </div>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pickCarModal" class="btn btn-primary pull-right pick-car-btn">Pick Car</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
             <!-- Available car 1 end -->

              <div class="row">
              <!-- Available car 2 start -->
              <div class="col-md-12 available_car">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 available_car_img">
                  <img src="http://www.showroominfo.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/skoda-car.jpg" style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
                  <p>Car Name 2</p>
                  <p> 5 Seater </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 available_car_info col-xs-8">
                  <div class="features col-md-12 pull-left ">
                      <p class="features-header">Car Features</p>
                      <P><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>Air conditioning</p>
                      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color"></span>Automatic</p>
                      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>3 Bags</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="available_car_prices col-xs-12 col-md-7" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                  <div class="price-box price-box-left col-sm-3">
                    <h4 class="price-heading">Rental price</h4>
                    <h4 class="price-amount">$143.00</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-box price-box-middle col-sm-5">
                    <h4 class="price-heading">Total Price</h4>
                    <h4 class="price-amount">$143.00</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-box price-box-right col-sm-3">
                    <h4 class="price-heading">Free Milage</h4>
                    <h4 class="price-amount">$143.00</h4>
                  </div>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pickCarModal" class="btn btn-primary pull-right pick-car-btn">Pick Car</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is the JQuery Code that I have right now. I am new to traversing in JQuery so please let me know where the mistake is and how to fix it. Thank you

```
$(".pick-car-btn").click(function(){

  var imageSource = $(this).closest("div.available_car_img").find("img").prop("src");
  console.log(imageSource);

});
```

Comment: `.available_car_img` is not a parent or ancestor of `.pick-car-btn`, hence it won't find the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `.closest("div.available_car")`

```
var imageSource = $(this).closest("div.available_car").find("div.available_car_img > img").attr("src");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way.Because you were finding child div with `.closest()` which won't find anything.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/r19bjrgm/8/)

```
$(".pick-car-btn").click(function(){
  var imageSource = $(this).closest("div.available_car").find("div.available_car_img > img").attr("src");
  console.log(imageSource);
  alert(imageSource);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the $(this) keyword until you set the context - because in your code, the "this" keyword refers to the button pressed.
According to your code, you are going up from the button to the divlavailable_car_img, and then back down to the img.

Instead, just use the data target info to go to that element with the id

```
$(".pick-car-btn").click(function(){
    var $targetParent = $(this).data("target"); // grabs string value
    $parentTarget = $($imageTarget); // creates jQuery object referencing that element with that id // this assumes 
    /* from here, go down with find the img, assuming only one is within the parentTarget */
    var $imageSource = $parentTarget.find('img');
    $imageSource = $imageSource.prop('src');
    console.log($imageSource);
});
```

You're targeting data-target="#pickCarModal from the button, but I'm not seeing the modal with id="pickCarModal" in your code here.

It really depends on the structure on your HTML.
.closest() bubbles up to the parents
.find() goes down through descendents